# Generalization of Poincare Lemma for vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Poincaré Lemma implies that for any vector field $A\in \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $\nabla \cdot A = \text{div }A = 0$,  we can express locally this vector field as $A = \nabla \times B = \text{rot }B$, where $B$ is another vector field.

Can we say something similar with respect to a symmetric 2-tensor field $\Sigma$ that satisfies $\nabla\cdot\Sigma = 0$?

Note: $\nabla\cdot\Sigma = \sum_{k=1}^3 \cfrac{\partial \Sigma_{ik}}{\partial x^k}$

Comment: You can think of $\Sigma$ as a collection of 3 vector fields, and the lemma applies to each one individually.

Comment: The index notation in the expression you're written doesn't seem to make sense. Are $i,j$ free or bound indices? By applying the argument from my previous comment, you should be able to show that there exists a 2-tensor $T$ such that $\Sigma_{ij}=\epsilon_{jkl}\partial_k T_{il}$.